# I want to do conditional styling based off the text inside a element but I got this far and am now clueless

Tags: javascript, iteration, onload, styling

So, I want to be able to upload this script as a separate file and change the style of certain tags and sub-tags based off of different values. For example, if a tables `<td>` element has a inner html of "blue", it will change to blue when the body loads; but I will need to get sub elements, their sub elements, etc. Here is the code:

```
function getTags() {
  // Get all of the tags inside of the body
  var mainnodes = document.body.childNodes;

  // Get the number of nodes in the body
  var mainlength = mainnodes.length;

  // Assign the variable for the subnodes an their nodes and so on later
  var subnodes, thirdnodes, fourthnodes, fifthnodes = ["Taco cat"];

  // Create the for loop to iterate until all of the body elements have been passed throuh
  for (i = 0; i < mainlength; i++) {

    // Get the current node being passed through
    var current = mainnodes[i];

    // Get the number of subnodes
    var sublength = current.childNodes.length;

    // See if the body element does not have any subnodes
    if (sublength === 0) {
      continue;
    } else {
      for (c = 0; c < sublength; c++) {
        subElements(current.childNodes[c]);
      }
    }  // End of the: no body element sub element if statement


  } // End of the body element for loop


} // End of the get tags functions


function subElements(toiterate) {

  var giveback = ["Hello World"];
  for (a = 0; a < toiterate.length; a++) {
    var current = toiterate[i];
    var subs = current.childNodes;

    if (subs.length === 0) {
      continue;
    } else {

      for (b = 0; b < subs.length; b++) {

        if (b === 0) {
          giveback = subs[b];
        } else {
          giveback += subs[b];
          if (b == subs.length) {
          }
        }

      }




    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jedbkmrw/

Comment: Thank you so much! That is so much easier.